# property or method by DISPID

Tags: windows, com, ole

Is it possible to know if a given DISPID (result of GetIDsOfNames) is either a method, a property getter or setter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell this by obtaining the `INVOKEKIND` enumeration for the DISPID.  Take a look at [ITypeInfo::GetFuncDesc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221023.aspx).  For an example how to do this check out the implementation of the ATL function `AtlGetFuncInfoFromId`.